# SwiftUI - Navigation View title is overlapping list

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a simple list with a navigation view, where the navigation view is overlapping the list while scrolling.

Here is the look I want.
[image]

Here is what I am getting with the overlap
[image]

Here is the code

```
struct MedicalDashboard: View {
let menuItemData = MenuItemList()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(menuItemData.items, id: \.id) { item in
            MenuItemRow(menuItem: item)
        }
        
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .navigationTitle("Dashboard")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                Button(action: {
            // TODO: - Pop up a sheet for the settings page.
            print("User icon pressed...")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle").imageScale(.large)
        }
                            
        )
        .padding(.top)
    }

}
```

}

when I add padding(.top) the overlap stops but I get a different color background on the navigation
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Xcode 13.4, except a missing `}`, without the `.padding(.top)` and with a custom `List` everything works like a charm for me.

The problem might come from `MenuItemList()`.

I have still updated your code by replacing `.navigationBarItems` and by adding the sheet for you:

```
struct MedicalDashboard: View {

    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            List { // Custom list
                Text("Hello")
                Text("Salut")
            }
            .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
            .navigationTitle("Dashboard")
            .toolbar() { // .navigationBarItems will be deprecated
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        showSheet.toggle()
                        print("User icon pressed.")
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { /* SettingsView() */ }
                }
            }

        }

    } // New

}
```

Edit your post and show us `MenuItemList()`.

Comment: In my case using toolbar not working..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Swift

```
struct MedicalDashboard: View {
    init() {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
    }

    ...
}
```